# Gmail keyboard shortcut to jump to next page of older messages

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts

I've been searching around the internet for the last hour, but mysteriously somehow, I've been unable to find the Gmail keyboard shortcuts to hop to the page of the next 50 older or newer messages (or even find people frustrated if they don't exist).

I know about the <kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>K</kbd> for moving up and down the current window, but once I get to the bottom of the current page, I want to be able to hop on to the next messages. Do these shortcuts just not exist?

Edit: I wanted to update this since this question is getting some traffic. There appears to be no way to do this when you have tabs enabled. However, switching to priority inbox (or maybe just disabling tabs) makes `J` and `K` move from page to page.

Comment: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6594?hl=en there all shortcuts are available for Gmail, if that is not listed there what you are looking for then its not exist buddy.

Comment: Seems like there is no shortcut for this. I could find shortcut for all action that I take frequently except this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems there is no shortcut for this.

I know two workarounds:

1. Press <kbd>,</kbd> (comma) to move focus to the toolbar, and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> a few times to get to the Older/Newer navigation buttons.
2. While walking through messages with <kbd>j</kbd> / <kbd>k</kbd>, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> a few times to walk backwards in the mailbox buttons until you reach the Older/Newer navigation buttons.

Answer (score 3):

Though there is no direct "next page" keyboard shortcut, the quickest way I've found to get there is by using the <kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd> shortcuts you mentioned in a slightly different way.

1. Hold down <kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd> until you reach the last/first message in the list
2. Release and then press <kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd> again

Note that this doesn't work for any of the various types of Inbox, but will work everywhere else (search results, Drafts, Sent, etc). For the Inbox, I use the first workaround @janos [suggested](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/53724/14503) with <kbd>,</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd> 3 or 4 times, and <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but I tend to find the <kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd> option quicker everywhere else.

It's frustrating there isn't a direct shortcut for this, but these workarounds serve me well enough until there is. It takes slightly more than a second for screens with 20 messages, and longer for those with more.

Comment: This does not work for me. I press `j` /`k` to get to the top /bottom of my messages, but pressing either `j`/`k` again does not change the page. Any suggestions?

Comment: I just realized this doesn't work for the Inbox, but seems to work everywhere else (search results, Drafts, Sent, etc). I just tested with all the types of Inboxes (Default, Priority Inbox, etc.), and it doesn't work for any of them. It makes sense it wouldn't for Priority Inbox and the similar ones, because they don't have the next/previous page buttons, but the fact that it doesn't for Default is just sad. I'll update my answer to point that out.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2020, shortcuts do exist and the shortcut is `g + n` for the next page and `g + p` for the previous page.

But for any keyboard shortcuts to work, you need to have them enabled in settings though!

You can find a detailed list of shortcuts [here in the google support page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6594?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

Answer (score 1):

Click on the number of pages/messages displayed tab at the top of the Gmail website. For eg. 1 of 50, and after clicking it will show the left and right arrows to navigate through pages of emails.

Answer (score 0):

A better method is to click on the 1 of 50 (or however many you have it set to show on page). This will bring up the older page forward/back options.

Answer (score 0):

After you load messages from the new page (e.g. with `,` and `Tab`) you can move between loaded pages with `Alt + arrowRight / Alt + arrowLeft`.

Answer (score 0):

You can move to view older and newer messages with

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>

I don't know why this isn't listed in any Google documentation, but I found the answer here: https://shortcutworld.com/en/Gmail/mac/all.  Works great for me (Mac with Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

I use <kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>K</kbd> to scroll through emails extensively! Great shortcut, but as is pointed out, there's no way to get past the 50 message limit. When I reach that limit I type this sequence: <kbd>G</kbd> then <kbd>I</kbd> then <kbd>U</kbd> (i.e. 'go to inbox' and 'return to threadlist'), then I scroll down if needed to get to the next message I want to read and continue with the <kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>K</kbd> sequence.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, after you navigate in the message list with <kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>K</kbd> shortcuts, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to go into a message. After that the <kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>K</kbd> shortcuts work next/previous message while within a message. If you enter a message with the click of a mouse/trackpad the shortcuts do not work.

Answer (score 0):

Create a bookmark and paste this code:

```
javascript:document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => { if(e.altKey) { const child = e.key === 'ArrowLeft' ? 2 : e.key === 'ArrowRight' ? 3 : 0; child && document.querySelector(`.h0>:nth-child(${child})`).click(); } });
```

Now when you go to Gmail, you can activate the keyboard shortcut by clicking on the bookmark. Use option-left or option-right on Mac (Alt-left or Alt-right on Windows) to go to the message before or after.

I didn't test this 100%, so YMMV.

Answer (score -1):

The shortcut is `Alt + Arrow Right/Left`, this will switch between Older/Newer pages on Gmail.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Can you expand your answer with complete instructions?

Answer (score -3):

The keyboard shortcut you are looking for is <kbd>J</kbd>.